What are hybrids? What are they a hybrid between?
One of the fundamental things in The Misfit of Demon King Academy is discrimination based on some demons being "hybrids", but either I missed it, or it was never explained what they are a hybrid of.
I did some looking on the net and didn't find any clarification either.  I don't think it's humans because of the giant wall, and demon-spirit hybrids are always specially called out, like in the tournament arc.  I don't think it's a demon-god hybrid either, since the gods in the show tend to cause so much trouble.

Japanese Wikipedia does not seem to mention even ハイブリッド=hybrid - isn't is just demon-human? (protagonist? is described as 父グスタ・母イザベラをもつ人間に近い魔族（混血）として転生する -- 混血 means multiracial)

I believe that a misfit in The Misfit of Demon King Academy is a person/creature furthest away from a demon king.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

How is that determined? From what I have seen it is determined by people who are part human or some other species.
